# Flutter Provider: Why does this error happens when calling Provider.of<Widget>(context) like tihis:

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm new to flutter and I'm testing Provider and can't figure out why doing this works (by work i mean it shows a list in the appbar):

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<Data>(
      builder: (context)=> Data(),
        child: MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: CustomText(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

With a CustomText class that does practically nothing:

```
class CustomText extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(Provider.of<Data>(context).texts.tostring());
  }
}
```

But this other thing throws a  - Could not find the correct Provider above this MyApp Widget - Error:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<Data>(
      builder: (context)=> Data(),
        child: MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text(Provider.of<Data>(context).texts.toString()),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The Data class is :

```
class Data with ChangeNotifier{
  List<String> _texts = ['Text 1', 'Text 2', 'Text 3', 'Text 4',];

  get texts {
    return _texts;
  }

  void deleteText(int index){
    this._texts.removeAt(index);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void addText(String text){
    this._texts.add(text);
  notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

I just can not see what is the difference or why that matters. Shouldn't that code be equivalent? Any insight will be much appreciated.

Comment: That is because you're still returning a List. You could change it into `return _texts.toString();` and called it through the `CustomText` widget.

Comment: The fact that it is returning alit does not matter whatsoever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that in the `CustomText` case, `context` is from its parent widget which is `MyApp`, whereas in the second case, `context` is from `MyApp`'s parent. Since your Provider is implemented inside `MyApp`, it cannot find the provider if you use `MyApp`'s parent's `context` (the second case)

Comment: Thanks. You are right, I moved the ChangeNotifierProvider to the runApp function and it worked.